# Código não funciona [PYTHON]

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Escrevi um script simples que capta as notas de alunos através de uma lista auxiliar e depois joga tudo dentro de uma lista maior, incluindo a média dos alunos que é calculada durante o código.
Criei um while com a flag 999 para sair da iteração e o programa permite que o usuário (que poderia ser um professor por exemplo) acesse as notas do aluno para entender a média que é mostrada no menu.
O usuário precisa digitar um número indexador, caso ele digite um `out of range` o programa fica preso no loop até que ele digite um número válido. 
O problema é que depois que eu digito uma vez um indexador inexistente ele continua preso no loop mesmo depois de eu digitar um indexador válido.
Segue código:

```
dados = []
geral = list()
while True:
    dados.append(input('Nome do aluno: '))
    dados.append(float(input('Nota 1: ')))
    dados.append(float(input('Nota 2: ')))
    media = (dados[1] + dados[2]) / 2
    dados.append(media)
    geral.append(dados.copy())
    dados.clear()
    resp = ' '
    while resp not in 'SN':
        resp = input('Quer cadastrar mais alunos? [S/N] ').strip().upper()[0]
    if resp == 'N':
        break
print('-' * 35)
print('ALUNOS CADASTRADOS'.center(35))
print('-' * 35)
print(f'{"Código":<8}{"Nome":<17}{"Média Final":5}')
for i, (nome, n1, n2, media) in enumerate(geral):
    print(f'{i:<8}{nome:<15}{media:5}')
print()
relatorio = 0
while relatorio != 999:
    relatorio = int(input('Você quer analisar as notas de qual aluno? (DIGITE 999 para PARAR) '))
    while relatorio not in range(len(geral)):
        relatorio = input(f'Aluno não existente. Digite um número entre 0 e {len(geral) - 1}: ')
    print(f'Histórico de notas do aluno {geral[relatorio][0]}: ', end='')
    print(f'{geral[relatorio][1]}, {geral[relatorio][2]}')
print('PROGRAMA DE NOTAS ENCERRADO.')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução é validares se o valor que inseres existe o número de posições no dict, variável "geral".

**file.py**

```
dados = []
geral = list()
while True:
    dados.append(input('Nome do aluno: '))
    dados.append(float(input('Nota 1: ')))
    dados.append(float(input('Nota 2: ')))
    media = (dados[1] + dados[2]) / 2
    dados.append(media)
    geral.append(dados.copy())
    dados.clear()
    resp = ' '
    while resp not in 'SN':
        resp = input('Quer cadastrar mais alunos? [S/N] ').strip().upper()[0]
    if resp == 'N':
        break
print('-' * 35)
print('ALUNOS CADASTRADOS'.center(35))
print('-' * 35)
print(f'{"Código":<8}{"Nome":<17}{"Média Final":5}')
for i, (nome, n1, n2, media) in enumerate(geral):
    print(f'{i:<8}{nome:<15}{media:5}')
print()
relatorio = 0
while relatorio != 999:
    relatorio = int(input('Você quer analisar as notas de qual aluno? (DIGITE 999 para PARAR) '))
    if relatorio < len(geral):
      print(f'Histórico de notas do aluno {geral[relatorio][0]}: ', end='')
      print(f'{geral[relatorio][1]}, {geral[relatorio][2]}')
print('PROGRAMA DE NOTAS ENCERRADO.')
```